# PHP = append a 0 to the end of a string

Tags: php

I have this function which takes the average user rating given to an item and converts it to a relevant class:

```
function get_user_rating_class($urate_ave){
    if($urate_ave==='0.0'){
        $user_rating_class='unrated_u';
    }else{
        $round_to = 0.5;
        $rounded = round($urate_ave / $round_to) * $round_to;
        $removedec = str_replace('.','',$rounded);
        if(strlen($removedec)<2){$removedec.'0';}
        $user_rating_class='rating_user_'+$removedec;
    }
    return $user_rating_class;
}
```

No when I put a value, say 3.0 into the function it should come out as rating_user_30 but instead it is coming out as rating_user_3, so there must be something wrong with this line:

`if(strlen($removedec)<2){$removedec.'0';}`

I thought it might be because It was treating the value $removedec as a number rather than a string so I tried adding this line just before it, but no change:

```
$removedec = strval($removedec);
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: please fire whoever came up with `$urate_ave`. thanks. Or at least buy him Clean Code by Robert Martin.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean, just googled robert martin and there are a lot about.

Comment: Code is much more often read than it is written. Thus, code should be readable. Using abbreviations like `$urate_ave` instead of `average_user_rating` makes your code unreadable. The few keystrokes you save with the abbreviation are not worth the readability you sacrifice there. Someone seeing that `urate_ave` will have a hard time figuring out what it means. As for Clean Code: http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882

Comment: I do agree and I do tend to use more descriptive variable names now (much like my function names - get_user_rating_class) - this is part of some old code that I am reworking. However, as for it not being clear what it means - you seem to have cracked my code. Thanks for the link, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `.=` instead of `.` to append a value to a string *and* set the variable to that value.  The dot operator alone will append the value but not change the variable's value.

```
$removedec .= '0';
```

Comment: silly mistake... thanks. My trailing numbers are coming out fine now, but I have lost an underscore, e.g I am getting  rating_user 30 instead of user_rating_30, for a bonus point can you see how I've managed that one?

Comment: Never mind, I used a + instead of a . - I guess thats the problem flipping between js and php

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right that line is wrong, you forgot to assign the value, like this:

```
if(strlen($removedec)<2){$removedec=$removedec.'0';}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is a integer variable and you do not know what the value is then:

```
$var = 0;
$str = "var is : " . ($var?$var:'0');
```

attache the value at the end of string.